# MemberOf Expand not Populating Collection

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

```
var client = ActiveDirectoryClientFactory.GetActiveDirectoryClient(_connector);
client.Context.MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;
_withOwnedDevices = await client.Users.Expand(d => d.OwnedDevices).ExecuteAsync();
_withMemberOf = await client.Users.Expand(d => d.MemberOf).ExecuteAsync();
```

When running the above code I do get OwnedDevices but MemberOf comes back empty all the time.

```
var client = ActiveDirectoryClientFactory.GetActiveDirectoryClient(_connector);
_withOwners = await client.Devices.Expand(d => d.RegisteredOwners).ExecuteAsync();
_withUsers = await client.Devices.Expand(d => d.RegisteredUsers).ExecuteAsync();
_withMemberOf = await client.Devices.Expand(d => d.MemberOf).ExecuteAsync();
```

Similiarly running the above nets RegisteredOwners and RegisteredUsers but nothing on the MemberOf collection.

```
var client = ActiveDirectoryClientFactory.GetActiveDirectoryClient(_connector);
var matches = await client.Users.Where(u => u.Mail == email).Expand(u => u.MemberOf).ExecuteAsync();
```

This nets a list of matches, one, and the MemberOf collection has results. Querying the same Active Directory in all cases.

The problem seems to be related to the need for the special MergeOption. Without AppendOnly or NoTracking I get an exception when making the second of two calls with different Expand options. I do a similar thing with devices and do not have to set the MergeOption at all and the context merges the objects no problem so both expanded collections are shown on the entity. In the case of users if you try the same thing the ActiveDirectoryClient throws a "The context is already tracking a different entity with the same resource Uri." In testing with Devices that problem only creeps in when trying to do an expand on MemberOf, can do multiple calls to expand other collections but once I try with MemberOf you get the tracking exception.

Answer (score 0):

I tested below code:

```
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();

            client.Context.MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;
            var _withMemberOf = await client.Users.Expand(d => d.MemberOf).ExecuteAsync();
```

Above code will return page Collection of the users. Max number of users in current page is 100.Each user has a MemberOf property which shows the groups and roles memberships of the user .Blow is a screenshot when debug in vs:
[image]

Please check whether the user you successfully get MemberOf collection via :

```
var client = ActiveDirectoryClientFactory.GetActiveDirectoryClient(_connector);
var matches = await client.Users.Where(u => u.Mail == email).Expand(u => u.MemberOf).ExecuteAsync();
```

is included in the CurrentPage collections , you could use below code to get the next page collection of users to check that :

```
            client.Context.MergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly;
            IPagedCollection<IUser> pagedCollection = await client.Users.Expand(d => d.MemberOf).ExecuteAsync();
            if (pagedCollection != null)
            {
                do
                {

                    //loop the users and get the memberof information

                    pagedCollection = await pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync();
                } while (pagedCollection != null);

            }
```

Comment: When I use the expand on the IUserCollection directly as in the first code the MemberOf collection is empty.

When I use the expand on the IReadOnlyQueryableSet, because of the where, in the second code I get a populated MemberOf collection.

I have no problem getting the pages, the inconsistent behavior of the MemberOf collection while trying to get the list of users is hurting me.

Comment: @ Montane Hamilton , what do you mean by MemberOf collection is empty when use first code . I have add a screenshot in my answer,you will find it has the results ,please check that .

Comment: Do what you are doing but do a call to get the users and expand OwnedDevices, then do the same call with an expand on the memberOf. No error but the MemberOf collection will be empty.

If I do only a call to users and expand MemberOf, I get the collection populated.

Third do the multiple call test but remove the setting of the merge option and it all blows up with an exception due to the context handling some objects badly and is tracking multiple entities with the same URI.

Comment: @Montane Hamilton ,The reason why this exception is occurring is that your deserialized type does not exactly match the Type of the tracked entity. To avoid this, you can use no tracking option(client.Context.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;) or use a new ActiveDirectoryClient for each logical operation.

Comment: Right and I can do this but getting an entity that has more than one collection populated does not work anymore. If I do it with tracking on other types it will merge the entities without issue. With the MemberOf collection the collision happens when it should not. If I could expand on more than one collection then I could do it in a single call but having to do it in two separate calls works on some entities and not on others.